# Function gets logged on second call

Tags: angular, typescript

When I call component function for the first time this.products is undefined.
After second call I see correct result.

I also tried using Observable with the same result. I checked console logs on different browsers.

```
//Service function
  getProducts()
  {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(this.serverUrl + '/products').pipe(map(data => data));
  }


//Component function
  getProducts(){
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => (this.products = data));
    console.log(this.products);
  }
```

Comment: console.log is called before you get your data that's why you have undefined and then the actual products. Putting the log in the subscription should resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should amend how you handle your subscription just a little.

Try the following.

```
public getProducts(): void
{
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(data => 
    {
        this.products = data;
        console.log(this.products);
    });
  }
```

---

The  HTTP call is an asynchronous task, so you need to do the assignment and the logging from inside the subscription, other wise the `console.log();` runs as soon as the asycn call has began. (Aysnc takes some unknown amount of time).

Comment: @Yamah - In other words, "getProducts()" makes an *asynchronous* call, and hence returns *BEFORE A VALUE IS RECEIVED*. Unless you "subscribe" with a callback".  As dince12's solution correctly does.  He also puts the "console.log()" in the same callback.

Comment: Your response was (and is) 100% correct.  I just wince when I see missing ";".  It's legal JS to leave them off - but it's "good practice" to include them.  IMHO...

Comment: I 100% agree, just overlooked, probably because I copied it from the question and spaced it out :-)